# Responding to "that's not a Jewish name"

Tags: names, social-convention

My ancestry is not eastern-European, and sometimes when I meet people in a Jewish setting and we introduce ourselves, I'm met with "that's not a Jewish name" (referring to my last name, mostly).  I don't think the person saying this means to challenge me; it's just an observation.  But it seems to call for a reply, and I'm never sure what to say.  "There are Jews in Italy", while true, feels a little dismissive, but the details of my family background really aren't relevant most of the time.  I understand that Miss Manners would call for something like "why does that concern you?", but that doesn't feel like an appropriate *Jewish* response to me somehow.

In a casual encounter with a stranger who does not appear to be trolling, how should one respond to this kind of statement?  Is there any factor in one's background that, if present, would affect how one responds -- does the answer change if you're the product of an intermarriage, the descendant of a convert, a convert yourself, the descendant of crypto-Jews (marranos), etc?

(No, I'm not going to change my name to dodge this problem.)

Comment: It may not be a Jewish name, but it is the name of a Jew.

Comment: That sort of question itself is not an appropriate *Jewish* question.  "My father's family is from Italy" seems like a reasonable answer to me.

Comment: I think the right response would depend on the social/conversational context in which the challenge was made. For example, if it's someone for whose social/Jewish education you are responsible (e.g. your child or student), it may make more sense to teach them about variant Jewish migration patterns and not making assumptions; if it seems like the person's trolling, a curt response like "I guess it is." may be most appropriate; etc.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, thanks.  It's not an appropriate Jewish question, no, but that's not under my control.  Also, the person saying it might be unaware, or distracted (e.g. this happened to me at a shiva minyan last night).

Comment: Just say "It is Armenian for 'schwartz'"

Comment: @MonicaCellio, My point is that there's a whole multi-dimensional spectrum of possible contexts, each of which could warrant a different response.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, thanks.  Does my edit help?

Comment: Do you have a hebrew name? If so you can just say that Monica is the non hebrew name. If you don't have a hebrew name say that it was common to call jewish girls Monica in italy. My none hebrew name is mark and in America it is a common none jewish name but in Eastern Europe if you were named mark you would definitely be a jew. Not only Eastern Europe but in Italy too. I was named after Marcelo mastriani the jewish Italian actor.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, it does make the question more specific and therefore more answerable. It's probably specific enough that someone might have a good "Ms. Manners style" guideline that covers it well enough for most situations.

Comment: Someone once attacked Rabbi Fabian Schoenfeld shlit'a, the dean of Queens rabbis, *ad hominem* because of his first name. I heard Rabbi Rakeffet point out that there is a Tosafist named "Rabbeinu Peter."

Comment: You could always just reply with, "That's true."

Comment: Heh, I'm a ger with a Germanic last name, so I have the inverse situation. If I were a McDowell or something (actually I'm Mackenzie and Helsher on my mother's side) I would probably devolve to something like "I bet Goldberg wouldn't have sounded particularly Jewish to Moshe Rabbeinu," but I guess that's a bit aggressive

Comment: @Shalom The tosafist is רב פטר which could be Peter or _peter_ like _peter chamor_, particular if that tosafist was a firstborn.

Comment: "Neither is <`insert non-jewish sounding name of famous Jewish person here`>" e.g. `Miller`, `Mason`, etc.

Comment: I think you could say "Did you mean you didn't think it's a Jewish name?" That way, you are correcting how s/he should have phrased his/her statement. In addition you are putting them 'on the spot' because they won't answer 'no' unless they're really rude, thus they will learn that their statement lacked sensitivity.

Comment: I think there are two reasons for someone to ask that: Either they are rude, or they want to know the origins of the name. So answer them in that light. If you think they are being rude, then just say "Ok". If you think they are curious about the name, then tell them it's from ...., etc.

Comment: ask them if Berman or Shtreicher are Jewish?

Answer (score 4):

This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_surnames) gives the background on the development of Jewish surnames.

The range of sources for such names includes:

- the place from which the family came
- translation of the Hebrew patronymic
- the Austrian emperor Joseph the second issued a decree called Das
  Patent über die Judennamen which compelled the Jews to adopt German
  surnames.
- Napoleon also, in a decree of July 20, 1808, insisted upon the Jews
  adopting fixed names
- a tendency to translate Biblical names into French
- Toponyms form, perhaps, the larger number of surnames among modern
  Jews
- trades and occupations

You could direct the person to this article or better try to find the origin of your surname and explain it to the enquirer emphasizing that essentially surnames were imposed upon us!

As you probably know, (Wikipedia)

> Cellio is a comune (municipality) in the Province of Vercelli in the
>   Italian region Piedmont, located about 80 km northeast of Turin and
>   about 45 km north of Vercell